# htaccess Redirect from folder to external URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to setup a redirect from URL domain1.com/c/name1 to URL abc.domain2.com/ID1

In my root htaccess file I tried the following redirect statement, but unfortunately it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/c/name1(/) https://abc.domain2.com/ID1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem might be, that I'm using a DNS setting to root the  domain1.com to an external IP address, which is my landing page platform.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/c/name1(/) https://abc.domain2.com/ID1 [R=301,L]
> ```

The URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against does not start with a slash. You are also enforcing the trailing slash, which is not present on your example URL.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^c/name1/?$ https://abc.domain2.com/ID1 [R=301,L]
```

The `/?` makes the trailing slash optional.

> The problem might be, that I'm using a DNS setting to root the domain1.com to an external IP address, which is my landing page platform.

I'm not sure what you mean by this, but the `.htaccess` file will need to be the root directory of wherever `domain1.com` resolves to.

Comment: I have an A record in my DNS settings for the domain1.com pointing to an external IP address, where I have no access to. Hence, this rewrite rule would not work, right?
But I also have several subdomains, pointing to folders in my root, where I have access to. E.g. dl.domain1.com points to the folder /dl. Would it make sense to use dl.domain1.com instead of domain1.com and put the rewrite rule into the htaccess file in the subfolder dl?

Comment: If `domain1.com` points to an external server then this is obviously not going to work. If `dl.domain.com` points to a local subdirectory then yes, you could place the rule in that subdirectory and redirect `dl.domain.com/c/name1` instead (if that makes sense for _you_ - to use a different hostname?). But as mentioned in my answer, that slash prefix on the URL-path was certainly a problem that would need to be fixed.